# MS SQL Server- COMMENT on Table for Remarks

Tags: sql-server, dictionary, comments, remarks

When I run the sp_tables I see a remark field. I know in other SQL programs, I can comment on table, but that's not working in MS SQL Server. I have tried looking this up, but I'm not getting anywhere. I was hoping to be able to use this feature instead of creating a table for a data dictionary.

```
-- Table Information
exec sp_tables mytable;

-- Want to add to the remark column

-- Comment ode this doesn't work:
comment on table mytable is  'TEST';
```

Thank you !

Comment: Sounds like what you want a extended properties.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  -->
                     EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'hello table LangTest' ,@level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'LangTest'

Comment: Thank you both! I did get it to work in the extended properties by using your comments. I was originally thinking I could populate the remarks field in the SP table itself.